# renderPage is not a function, when building vue SSR project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, vite

I'm trying to run a vue vite project with SSR. The build command generated a client and a server folder, inside of the server me is a main.js file for SSR. I'm trying to run a node.js server with express.js.

```
const nodeFetch = require('node-fetch');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

//@ts-ignore
global.fetch = nodeFetch;

const dist = `../dist`;


// This contains a list of static routes (assets)
/** @type {import('../dist/server/package.json')} */
const {
    ssr: { assets }
} = require(`${dist}/server/package.json`);


/** @type {import('../dist/client/ssr-manifest.json')} */
const manifest = require(`${dist}/client/ssr-manifest.json`);

// This is the server renderer we just built
/** @type { import('../dist/server/main')} */
const { default: renderPage } =
    /*@ts-ignore*/
    require(`${dist}/server`);


const server = express();

for (const asset of assets || []) {
    server.use(
        '/' + asset,
        express.static(path.join(__dirname, `${dist}/client/` + asset), {
            maxAge: '24h'
        })
    );
}

server.get('*', async (request, response) => {
    const url =
        request.protocol + '://' + request.get('host') + request.originalUrl;

    const { html } = await renderPage(url, {
        manifest,
        preload: true,
        request,
        response
    });

    response.end(html);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
console.log(`Server started: http://localhost:${port}`);
server.listen(port);
```

I've followed an example project implementing SSR and it was doing the same thing. I'm a bit stuck here and not sure on how get SSR running with the project.

Comment: The error is :
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: renderPage is not a function

    at /application/dist/nodeindex.js:45:28

    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

    at next (/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)

    at Route.dispatch (/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)

    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)